# CodeName1 - Different response codes between ipa and source code

Tags: java, ios, xcode, codenameone

In the app I'm developing I can request content updates from a server. This works ok on Android, but on IOS it frequently (but not always) crashes. Given that this only happens on devices and not on the simulator to debug it I downloaded the source code, but I am get different results when running it from XCode than when installing and running the corresponding .ipa downloaded from the CN1 site. On the following code segment:

```
if (httpResponseCode == 200) {
    //useData, validations and others
    status = "OK_CONN";
} else {
    status = "ERROR_CONN";
}
```

when running the .ipa installed app receives 200 , continues and crashes, while the XCode one doesn't even connect to the update serve (and so informs of the failed connection and continues running normally)

I am suspecting different build settings, the only thing I changed from the default was disabling bitcode (and adding the certificates for signing). Is there any other setting I should be aware of? Or any other possible cause for the different behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running physically on the device or in the iOS simulator?

I'm guessing the latter so the connectivity issue might be related to the difference between the device and simulator.

The code should be identical as in the servers we don't build with bitcode either.

Comment: I'm running it on physical devices, tried ipod 5, and an (old) iphone, same issue on both of them.

Comment: It might be related to the version of xcode used to compile the code. On our servers we still use xcode 5.x which won't run on newer versions of Mac OS (and visa versa). However, locally we do run with Xcode 7+ without a problem so this might be an edge case behavior of the NSURL class. Try setting a proxy to monitor network traffic to see how it differs as this might give us a clue of the differences to investigate.